# How to call javascript function specified in a child <frame>

Tags: javascript, html, frame, frameset

I'm working on a ancient project which is based on  and  tags.

Here's the common HTML structure of the parent page (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>  
</head>
<frameset rows="75px,*" frameborder="0">
    <frame name="frame1" src="frames/frame1.html">
    <frameset class="child_frameset">
        <frame name="frame3" src="frames/frame3.html">
    </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Here how I specify the javascript function on the child frame (frame3.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function helloWorld(){
            alert('hello world!');
        }
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <h1>I'm frame 3</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My task is to call **helloWorld()** function. How do I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: are trying to call the function from the parent?

Comment: yes! I'm trying to call the **helloWorld()** function from the parent page (index.html)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
document.getElementById('frame3').contentWindow.helloWorld();
```

Comment: +1 Although it's probably a good idea to give the frame the ID first.

Comment: The frames in the example don't have an id, so `getElementById` isn't really appropriate. With just a name use `window.frames["frame3"].helloWorld()` instead.

Comment: Thanx for a quickest reply... I tried all of this but firebug console returns me **window.frames.frame3 is undefined** and **document.getElementById("frame3") is null** (please note I gave frame an id="frame3") ... any thoughts why?

Comment: It's actually works! With one simple tune ... I had to specify the DOM lad event and then trigger the function `$(window).load(function(){ document.getElementById("frame3").contentWindow.helloWorld();
});` ... works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You can call method from childframe

```
window.frames[n].frames[m].methodName()
```

where n , m are integers starting from 0.If you have document 
only one frame remove the frames[m] part and get the job done.

Ya one more thing , do trial an error and find out exact frame numbers
and method.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Check for contentWindow, contentDocument and get the frame object and perform call.

```
var siblingFrame;
if (parent.document.getElementById('siblingFrameId').contentWindow){
  siblingFrame = parent.document.getElementById('siblingFrameId').contentWindow;
} else if (parent.document.getElementById('siblingFrameId').contentDocument){
  siblingFrame = parent.document.getElementById('siblingFrameId').contentDocument;
} else if (parent.document.getElementById('siblingFrameId')) {
  siblingFrame = parent.document.getElementById('siblingFrameId');
}

siblingFrame.helloWorld();
```