# How can I call func in iframe from parent?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to call func which in iframe , from parent. 
If the func is in parent I could call it like : parent.func(); 
but I want to call func which is in iframe and I want to call it from parent?
js says I could not find func? How can I call it?

thanks

Comment: `childFrame.contentWindow.func()`?

Comment: sorry the question is already exists I delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either

```
window.frames['childFrame'].func();
```

or

```
document.getElementById('childFrame').contentWindow.func();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.helloWorld();

Ref : [How to call javascript function specified in a child <frame>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946656/how-to-call-javascript-function-specified-in-a-child-frame?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: please delete your answer I want to delete my question