# Execute javascript function in iframe using button in parent

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a simple function in the HTML inside of my iframe, also I use a button that executes the function onclick. What I would like to do is have the button on the parent page and work the same way.

```
    function saveEdits(){
        var editElem1 = document.getElementById("edit1");
        var userVersion1 = editElem1.innerHTML;
            localStorage.userEdits1 = userVersion1;

    <input type="button" value="Save Changes" onclick="saveEdits()"/></br>
```

What Would I do to put the button on the parent page and have it call the function in the iframe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call javascript function specified in a child <frame>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946656/how-to-call-javascript-function-specified-in-a-child-frame)

Comment: It is similar but not a duplicate, that just creates a frame that has a function inside of it that runs. Like an error message box.